# Prove that $\operatorname{int}(A)=i(A),$ where $i$ is the Kuratowski interior operator and $A\subseteq X,$ a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I know that the Kuratowski interior operator $i:\mathscr P(X)\to\mathscr P(X)$ satisfies the following axioms:

(I$1$) $i(X)=X;$

(I$2$) $i(A)\subseteq A,\forall A\subset X;$

(I$3$) $i(i(A))=i(A),\forall A\subset X;$

(I$4$) $i(A\cap B)=i(A)\cap i(B),\forall A,B\subset X.$

Also from (I$2$) and (I$4$) it follows that:
$A\subseteq B\Rightarrow i(A)\subseteq i(B),\forall A,B\subset X.\tag{I5}$

Now if $i$ induces the topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$, then
$$\mathcal T=\{A\subseteq X:i(A)=A\}.$$

> Show that: $\operatorname{int}_{\mathcal T}(A)=i(A),\forall A\subseteq X.$

(From this point and onwards I'll use $A^\circ$ instead of $\operatorname{int}_{\mathcal T}(A).$)

To prove the same I started with for any subset $A$ of $X,$ we have: $A^{\circ}\subseteq A\Rightarrow i(A^\circ)\subseteq i(A),$ by (I$5$), but $A^\circ\in\mathcal T,$ and so $i(A^\circ)=A^\circ\subseteq i(A).$ But for the reverse inequality I am not sure about how I should start actually!

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$i(i(A))=i(A)$ according to I$3$ so that $i(A)\in\mathcal T$.

Moreover $i(A)\subseteq A$ according to I$2$ so apparantly $i(A)$ is an open subset of $A$.

Comment: I feel dumb now! Thanks sir understood...

Comment: You are not dumb, but just had a blind spot. Glad to help.